# JUNG2: How to draw a circle?

Tags: java, jung

I need to draw a circle around a vertex in [JUNG](http://jung.sourceforge.net/). The circle is defined by the vertex as center and a given radius r.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this, I guess. This will give you points for circle with given `radius`. To adjust resolution of points change `x+=0.01` to a bigger/smaller value as needed. To move circle centre to an arbitrary point `(p,q)`, just add it to `(x,y)`, that is `plot(x+p,y+q);`.

```
double radius = 3;
for (double x = -radius; x <= radius; x += 0.01) {
    double y = Math.sqrt(radius * radius - x * x);
    plot(x, y);//top half of the circle
    plot(x, -y);//bottom half of the circle
}
```

**EDIT**: It appears that JUNG is not really an XY-plot but a network/graph framework. So all you need is to layout your points in a circle using one of provided layouts. `CircleLayout` and `KKLayout` seem to do the trick, though `CircleLayout` gives strange results for when there are many nodes. Here's complete sample code:

```
//Graph holder
Graph<Integer, String> graph = new SparseMultigraph<Integer, String>();

//Create graph with this many nodes and edges
int nodes = 30;
for (int i = 1; i <= nodes; i++) {
    graph.addVertex(i);
    //connect this vertext to vertex+1 to create an edge between them.
    //Last vertex is connected to the first one, hence the i%nodes
    graph.addEdge("Edge-" + i, i, (i % nodes) + 1);
}

//This will automatically layout nodes into a circle.
//You can also try CircleLayout class
Layout<Integer, String> layout = new KKLayout<Integer, String>(graph);
layout.setSize(new Dimension(300, 300)); 

//Thing that draws the graph onto JFrame
BasicVisualizationServer<Integer, String> vv = new BasicVisualizationServer<Integer, String>(layout);
vv.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(350, 350)); // Set graph dimensions

JFrame frame = new JFrame("Circle Graph");
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.getContentPane().add(vv);
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
```

I have picked `SparseMultiGraph` because that's what was in [JUNG tutorial](http://www.grotto-networking.com/JUNG/JUNG2-Tutorial.pdf). There are other types of graphs, but I am not sure what the difference is.

You could also use a `StaticLayout` that can take `(x,y)` vertices, then use my original code to plot the points, but that would not be as elegant for JUNG framework. Depends on what your requirements are, however.

Comment: Hm, I am pretty new to java and jung, how to I apply this to an existing plot by JUNG using JFrame?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with JUNG myself. I guess you'll need to save previous `(x,y)` vertex into a variable and create an edge between previous and current in the loop. Then add your edge to the graph. Not sure about the exact API though. I'll give it a look, but it would be nice if someone else would post an answer with the correct API usage. Anyone?

Comment: I will accept this. I did get it to work, but i was not by using JUNG.